# How to share this data without global vars

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out the most logical, safe, efficient way to accomplish this, without using global variables.

Suppose I have a class:

```
class SomeClass{
 public: someFunction(){...}
};
```

And another class instantiates `SomeClass` as a data member:

```
class AnotherClass{
  SomeClass theTest;
  void anotherFunction(){...}
  int myDataInt;
 };
```

Now, I want the `someFunction` in `SomeClass` to be able to easily access the `myDataInt` in `AnotherClass`. One way would be to add an `int` parameter to `someFunction` that `AnotherClass` passes in. Perhaps that is the only decent way to do this. But I was hoping for a more "automatic" access between `someFunction` and `myDataInt`. Another option is to simply have `AnotherClass` set data in `SomeClass` that is equal to its own `myDataInt`. But then I have two classes storing the same data, which seems redundant.

Any other suggestions? Much appreciated.

Comment: How about `class AnotherClass { friend class SomeClass; ... };`. Other way is to have `getter()/setter()` for `myDataInt` which anyone can use accordingly.

Comment: Your example is so contrived as to be meaningless. There is no magic way for making some external variable automagically available to a method without passing it in. The real question is, why does one class need to be so intimately aware of the data of another class?

Comment: thanks @iammilind the `friend` idea is plausible, I'd not considered that.

Comment: This question kinda screams "refactor"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a pointer to the containing `AnotherClass` in `SomeClass`:

```
class SomeClass{
  AnotherClass* enclosing;
 public:
  someFunction(){
    int x=enclosing->myDataInt;
    ...
  }
};
```

EDIT: Also, as mentioned by iammilind above, you will want to either have `SomeClass` be a friend of `AnotherClass` or have an accessor method for `myDataInt`.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns, Nope, `myDataInt` is `private` according to your question.

Comment: @iammilind true but I could easily make a public accessor, no big deal on that point.

Answer (score 1):

A class should be responsible for its own state, thus you want each class member to be private and provide interfaces(member methods) to access them.

I won't introduce `friend` so easily if AnotherClass and SomeClass only shared a few fields between each other. A better design always try to keep data hidden to outside.

My solution to your question is SomeClass holds a pointer to AnotherClass then access it's member methods if needs to:

```
class AnotherClass;

class SomeClass
{
public: 
  SomeClass(AnotherClass* p) : context_ptr_(p) {}
  void someFunction(); 
  { 
      context_ptr_->setDataInt(3);
  }

private:
  AnotherClass *context_ptr_;
};


class AnotherClass
{
public:
  AnotherClass() :theTest(this)
  {         
  }
  void anotherFunction(){ }
  void setDataInt(int i) { myDataInt = i; }
private:
  SomeClass theTest;
  int myDataInt;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
class SomeClass{
 public:
    SomeClass( int & refInt )
        : sharedInt(refInt)
    {}

    int & sharedInt;
};
```

And in `AnotherClass`:

```
class AnotherClass {
  public:
    AnotherClass()
        : theTest(myDataInt)
    {}

  private:
    SomeClass theTest;
    int myDataInt;
 };
```

Comment: interesting, so instead storing the `int` value in two different places, one is merely a reference to the same data. if `myDataInt` changes in `AnotherClass`, even though it is private, `SomeClass` can still access it with the reference. Probably not the safest idea but I suppose it would work.

Comment: Why is it not safe?  From your example, `SomeClass` is purpose-built for use by `AnotherClass`.  The only thing to watch out for is that `AnotherClass` lives longer than `SomeClass`, or at least if it dies first then the reference is not used.  When you use references in classes like this it gives special semantics that pointers do not have.  That is, you *know* that the reference should *always* be valid.